# How to download logs created by ECS container to make them look the old-fashined way remove JSON?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, logging, download, legacy

My good old application creates log caught by AWS Cloudwatch logs

However it is ugly to read them trapped inside JSON. Can I get them in a raw form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `jq` (a C++ application without dependency hell) from your favourite package repository (or from [GitHub](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)).

Download the logs and parse them with

```sh
#profile=...
#lgn=...
aws --profile $profile logs get-log-events --log-stream-name
$lsn --log-group-name /$lgn | jq --raw-output '.events[] | .message'
```